# Different java packages & Visibility

Tags: java, visibility, package, naming

The question I'm asking is about a very frequent topic but I didn't find my exact question so I'm asking it explicitly.

I'm programming in java and I need to implement some classes, let's say A, B, C and D.
They are all part of an SDK and only D will be public (visible to the developer that will use my sdk).

A, B & C are classes dealing with different topics (let's say Bluetooth communciation, web services use & proprietary algorithms) although they need to communicate each other.
I'd like to divide classes in packages according to their "skill" (Public methods, Bluetooth, Web Services, Algorithms) but if I create different packages they won't be visible each other.

So, the only implementation I see here is a unique package and no modifier (so they will "see" each other and the user will only access to Class D).
Is there any way to create different packages in order to let me organize my sdk in a better way? (imagine a lot of classes, it could easily become a mess :) )

Thanks in advance for your help

Giorgio

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for this? The lack of visibility to the world does not automatically prevent one to use a class, if you had this in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, I don't think the Java language gives you a way to do it.

My understanding of your question is "I am developing an API in which I want to expose only certain classes and/or methods; other classes and/or methods in the package need to be used by the exposed ones, but I do not want them to be marked public and therefore available to a programmer using the API".

You don't say why this is necessary, or desirable.

The language does not support visibility this way.  You could possibly run the code you want to hide through an obfuscator, to (greatly) discourage anyone from understanding what those methods are and calling them, and of course not obfuscate the ones you want used, but that's as close as I can come up with.

Comment: You perfectly understood my needings,
the reason why I want to hide most of the implementation to the user is basically that most of the code is considered "proprietary".. for example:


- The protocol used to communicate with a bluetooth device 

- The protocol used to communicate with 3rd party servers

- Some Algorithms performed on the data obtained from the bluetooth above-mentioned device, etc..

Anyway I totally agree with you.. maybe some obfuscation and/or JNI can help me to discourage users from obtaining the soruce code/algorithms but this is all that java offers about this stuff :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct way to do this is to have a package which holds common interfaces and data (such as enums, simple classes such as Point etc...).
All other packages will refrence this common package,
where as their classes will implement the common interfaces.

This also gives you the benefit of true decoupling between the different packages.

Comment: I see your point and I'm trying to implement this for standard/common objects in my code, but imagine different "Shared Controllers" (such as Bluetooth Manager, Authentication Manager, Protocol Manager, etc..) that need visibility one to each other but still deal with different task areas, what to do with them?

Comment: Than think about using : IBlueToothmanager interface etc.. this will decouple your classes and is generally considerd a better design.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different packages for you classes, Just be sure they are public so they can be visible for other classes in other packages.